# Voting program should eliminate lowest candidate and add votes to another. Java

Tags: java, arrays

I've created a program that reads a text file and creates an array for the candidates and then creates an object for each voter along with an array for their preferences. The methods I'm having trouble with are the voting methods. For the candidate to win they must have more than half of the vote. So one method checks if they do or not and then deletes the candidate with the lowest vote count, the issue I'm having is after it deletes it I don't know how to check for their next preference.

Here is my method that does the voting

```
 public static int[] doVoting(Voter[] voters, String[] cand){

 // Create an int array to store votes
    int[] votes= new int[cand.length];


    //The first string of the candidates array will correspond to the first number in the int array

    for (int i=0; i< voters.length; i++){  
        for (int j=0; j< cand.length; j++){
            for (int k=0;k< voters[i].preferences.length; k++){
                if(voters[i].preferences[k].equals(cand[j]))
                {votes[j]= votes[j] + 1;
                }
                                    else 
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return votes;
}
```

Here is where it checks the votes and make a final decision

```
public static void doAlternativeVoteElection(Voter[] voters, String[] candidate)
{
    int[] votes = doVoting(voters,candidate);

    int max = votes[0];
    int min = votes[0];
    int sumVote = 0;
    int elemax=0;
    int elemin=0;

    for (int i=0;i<votes.length; i++){
        sumVote += votes[i];
        if (votes[i] > max){
            max=votes[i];
            elemax = i;
        }
        if(votes[i] <= min){
            elemin = i;
            min= votes[i];
        }
    }

    while (max <= sumVote/2)
    {

        candidate = arrayDel(elemin, candidate);
        System.out.println("he");
        votes= arrayDelInt(elemin, votes);
        votes = doVoting(voters, candidate);

        for (int i=0; i<candidate.length;i++){
            System.out.println(candidate[i]);
            System.out.println(votes[i]);
            if (votes[i]> max){
                max=votes[i];
                elemax = i;
            }
            else if(votes[i] <= min){
                elemin = i;
                min= votes[i];
            }
            else
                continue;


        }

        if(max > sumVote/2)
            break;
    }
    if(max > sumVote/2)
        System.out.println(candidate[elemax]+" wins");
}


public static int[] arrayDelInt(int min, int[] array)
{
    int[] retva = new int[array.length-1];


    for (int i=0; i<min; i++)
        retva[i] = array[i];

    for (int i=min+1; i<array.length; i++)
        retva[i-1] = array[i];


    return retva; 

}
```

The issue is that the doVoting method doesn't add the votes to the next preference after one candidate is eliminated. So eventually the arrayDel method just deletes all elements.

---

Here is the arrayDel method

```
    public static int[] arrayDelInt(int min, int[] array)
{
    int[] retva = new int[array.length-1];


    for (int i=0; i<min; i++)
        retva[i] = array[i];

    for (int i=min+1; i<array.length; i++)
        retva[i-1] = array[i];


    return retva; 

}
```

its the same for arrayDelInt

Comment: Can you also post the 'arrayDel()' and 'arrayDelInt()' methods? Is this a homework anyway? Are you restricted to use arrays only? What is the expected running time, memory cost of this task?

Comment: Yes this is homework and it need to just use arrays and those run time and memory dont matter.

Comment: Why don't you create a 'Candidate' class which holds an array of 'Voter' objects. It consumes a lot of memory, but you can find the lowest voted candidate in linear time in the worst case and you don't have to update neither max, nor min or anything like that, just taking the next lowest voted 'Candidate'.

Answer (score 0):

You've got two potential bugs that might be the issue.

`while (max <= sumVote/2)`  <--- Integer division is going to cause `sumVote/2` to round down.  Use `sumVote / 2.0` instead.  This is likely not it, but should be considered a potential bug anyway.

In this code in doVoting, given your stated requirements, believe the break statement should occur after vote count for a candidate has been incremented.  Try changing that last if block to look like the following

```
        if(voters[i].preferences[k].equals(cand[j])) {              
            votes[j]= votes[j] + 1;
            break;
        }
```

Comment: sumVote will always be the same in this. It's always going to be 12.

Comment: Then I'm misunderstanding your requirements.  Is this run-off voting until a particular candidate has >= 50% of the vote?  If so, then you must reset sumVote to 0 after running doVoting in your loop and recalculate, otherwise `(max <= sumVote/2)` is always going to resolve to true.

Comment: So what should be happening is if none of them have more than half the vote the candidate with the least votes is deleted. The people who voted for the deleted candidate vote again for their next preference. The number of total votes never changes

Comment: When I do that it just sets all of them to 12

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better to rethink you design to be more object oriented, something like; (please consider this pseudo-code)

```
public class Candidate {

    // maps the preference i.e. 1st, 2nd, etc. to votes cast
    private HashMap<String, int> votes = new HashMap<String, int>();

    public void addFirstPref() {
        votes.put("first", votes.get("first") + 1);
    }
    // and so on for addSecondPref() etc
}

public class Ballot {

    // maps preference to candidate
    HashMap<String, String> votes = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public String getFirstPref() {
        return votes.get("first");
    }
    // and so on for getSecondPref() etc.
}

public class Election {

    // populate a collection of candidates and ballots

    public void doVoting() {
        // count all the ballots
        for (Ballot ballot : ballotsColn) {
            candidatesColn.get(ballot.getFirstPref()).addFirstPref();
            // repeat for all preferences
        }

        // now do rounds until there's one left
        while (candidatesColn.size() > 1) {
            // find the candidate with the lowest first preferences
            // find all the ballots where that candidate is the first pref
            // iterate all those ballots, find the second pref candidate
            // add 1 vote to the first pref count of that candidate
            // remove the candidate from the collection
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: He must use arrays only. No hashmaps.

Comment: This seems way simpler, unfortunately we are required to use certain methods in certain ways

Comment: Ah, missed that requirement. Politics is so unnecessarily complicated :)

Comment: How about if you used *Candidate[] candidatesColn* and *Ballot[] ballotsColn* that wouldn't be far off what you are doing now, except it's arrays of objects instead of arrays of primitives. Similarly the HashMaps could be turned into arrays; *Candidate int[] votes* where *votes[0]* is 1st preferences, etc. And *Ballot String[] votes* where *votes[0]* is the candidate who got the first preferences, etc.